# Vue + Vuetify expansion panel enter/leave animation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently developing a webapp in Vue.js with the help of Vuetify.

I found the expansion panel element very usefull and I wanted to use it in my website.

So I easily get the data i want to display from Firebase and i proceed to load the items with this template:

```
    <v-expansion-panel popout>
      <v-expansion-panel-content
      v-for="doc in filteredclienti"
      :key="doc.id">
        <div slot="header">{{doc.data().Nome}} {{doc.data().Cognome}}</div>
        <v-card>
        Card content
        </v-card>
     </v-expansion-panel-content>
   </v-expansion-panel
```

Everything works fine, the panel is ok and the popup animation works fine too.

Now I'd like to display a simple enter/leave animation to each item.

I tried to add a `<transition-group>` tag after the `<v-expansion-panel popuot>` but the console tells me  want only a `<v-expansion-panel-content>` element.

So i tried to add `<transition-group>` inside `<v-expansion-panel-content>` but in this case the layout is no more correct and the popup animation is not working anymore.

How can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you're going to have to either go with the default expansion panel popout animation, or design your own expansion panel that animates the way you would like.

Comment: But I don't want to animate the expansion, I want to animate the enter/leave moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the trick, I've added a delete button, that will slide the "deleted" doc out.
enjoy.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-expansion-panel popout>
      <transition-group name="list" tag="v-expansion-panel">
        <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="doc in filteredclienti" :key="doc.id">
          <div slot="header">
            <span>{{doc.data}}</span>
            <v-btn class="error" @click="deleteItem(doc.id)">
              <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>
          <v-card>Card content</v-card>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </transition-group>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    filteredclienti: [
      { id: 1, data: "data1" },
      { id: 2, data: "data1" },
      { id: 3, data: "data1" },
      { id: 4, data: "data1" }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    deleteItem(id) {
      this.filteredclienti = this.filteredclienti.filter(d => d.id !== id);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}
</style>
```